# Criar uma procedure no PostGreSql

Tags: postgresql, trigger, stored-procedures

Eu criei uma banco de dados no PostGreSql de Alocação de Equipamentos aonde um ou muitos Equipamentos podem ser Alocados por um ou muitos Setores. Ou seja Tenho 3 tabelas nesta relação: Uma é a Tabela Setor com as colunas(CÓDIGO E NOME) :

```
CREATE TABLE public.setor
(
  setcod serial NOT NULL,
  setnome character varying(200) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_setor PRIMARY KEY (setcod)
)
```

A segunda é Equipamento com as colunas(CÓDIGO, NOME e STATUS), esta coluna STATUS por default no ato de cadastro de um equipamento passa a ser "NÃO ALOCADO":

```
CREATE TABLE public.equipamento
(
  eqcod SERIAL NOT NULL,
  ednome character varying(200) NOT NULL,
  edstatus character varying(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NÃO ALOCADO',
  CONSTRAINT pk_equipamento PRIMARY KEY (eqcod)
)
```

E por fim a Tabela ALOCA(código, data de alocação, data de devolução) que se relaciona com duas anteriores:

```
CREATE TABLE public.aloca
(
  alocod integer NOT NULL,
  alodtdevolucao date NOT NULL,
  alodtalocacao date NOT NULL,
  alo_eqcod integer NOT NULL,
  alo_setcod integer NOT NULL,
  alo_funcod integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_aloca PRIMARY KEY (alocod),
  CONSTRAINT fk_equipamento FOREIGN KEY (alo_eqcod)
      REFERENCES public.equipamento (eqcod) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_funcionario FOREIGN KEY (alo_funcod)
      REFERENCES public.funcionario (funcod) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_setor FOREIGN KEY (alo_setcod)
      REFERENCES public.setor (setcod) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

PERGUNTA:
 Como ficaria a Procedure que atualiza o STATUS do Equipamento para "ALOCADO" após este mesmo equipamento estiver sido vinculado a uma Alocação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que isso pode te ajudar.

Primeiro você cria a função:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aloca_equip()
RETURNS trigger AS $teste_trigger$
BEGIN
UPDATE equipamento SET edstatus = 'ALOCADO' WHERE eqcod = NEW.alo_eqcod;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$teste_trigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Depois o trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_aloca_equip
AFTER INSERT ON aloca
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE aloca_equip();
```